# jquery .on event running multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a script which has the following event

```
 $('body').off('click','#del').on('click', '#del', function() {
        //logic
 });
```

This script is linked by a number of other pages, and every time I click the button (#del) the function is being executed many times.

I read that by doing the .off before the .on, this will be solved, however I am still encountering this problem.

Any ideas please?

Comment: what exactly u want??

Comment: can you create a fiddle to reproduce the issue?

Comment: I think you can add the event as a generic function, without invoking it on each click.

Comment: The logic of the event handler is running multiple times, I want it to run once

Comment: Why don't you just $('#del').click(function(){}) ??? What is your goal?

Comment: $('#del').click(function(){})  is not working for some reason

Comment: Could you provide the DOM? I wonder if $('#del').click(function(){}) is not working because #del doesn't exist at the time you are interpreting that javascript.

Comment: I think so too because I am setting the html inside the same script by using the .html method.

Comment: If that is the case you should try constraining the on event to the container you're applying the html too instead of the body. You could also apply the .off call before updating the html in the container.

Alliteratively right after you apply the new html you could always create a new click event via  $('#del').click(function(){}) but that doesn't seem  as clean.

Comment: @Kelly - Please show all relevant code (HTML, `$.ajax()` calls, etc) and provide a more *real use* case of your problem. Do you have multiple buttons with an ID of `div`? Eg. `<button id="div">My Button</button><button id="div">My Button 2</button>`. And show your `// logic` from the snippet above.

Comment: @William Gates, That worked thank you! I changed the 'body' to the specific div id and it worked!

P.S. I did not attach the whole since it is quite complex as I have multiple scripts referencing the same page